# Why didn't the Death Eaters take Harry after Dumbledore's death?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Half Blood Prince*, after Snape killed Dumbledore, Harry came out of the Invisibility Cloak and attacked Snape.

Why didn't Death Eaters pick Harry at that time and take him to Voldemort?

Comment: A very good question. Bellatrix and Snape were standing right there. He'd been stunned and could easily have been restrained and taken to Big V

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Voldemort ordered them to leave him.

> ‘No!’ roared Snape’s voice and the pain stopped as suddenly as it had
>   started; Harry lay curled on the dark grass, clutching his wand and
>   panting; somewhere above him Snape was shouting, ‘Have you forgotten
>   our orders? Potter belongs to the Dark Lord – we are to leave him! Go!
>   Go!’

What's not clear is *why* he ordered them to leave him. I personally err on the side of Snape *intentionally misconstruing* Voldemort's orders that Harry Potter should be left in situ.

Comment: If Snape *intentionally constructed* Voldemort's orders, would he be able to face Voldemort later?

Comment: @ss - Since no-one saw him leave Harry, he could have just said that it wasn't safe to snatch him